# Explanation of output produced by the following quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, ibm-q-experience

I've recently started reading about quantum computing and I apologize in advance if this is (and I think it probably is) a very simple question.

I've created the following circuit.

[image]

I believe I understand this circuit. It sends qubit 1 through the Hadamard gate to give it a 50/50 chance of being 0 or 1. The C-NOT gate means, if `q[1]` is 0 then `q[0]` remains 0 and if `q[1]` is 1 then `q[0]` has a not gate applied to make it 1. Therefore, the two qubits are entangled. It does the same to entangle `q[1]` and `q[2]` and for that reason, when the three are measured it is always 000 or 111 with a 50/50 chance of each. (I may not have understood this part well so if this is wrong, please verify my misunderstanding).

I've been fiddling with a similar circuit by adding a Hadamard gate to the third qubit at the beginning which is this circuit producing the below result.
[image]

[image]

I don't quite understand how those are the four possible results so please can someone explain how this circuit works. Many thanks

Comment: Hi @Dan! For an intro understanding of quantum computing, using 50/50 will work, but it's imperative that you understand linear algebra and braket notation if you'd like to get deeper. The power of quantum computing emerges from destructive / constructive interference, which can only occur with complex amplitudes.

Comment: @C.Kang Thanks for the advice. I've been doing things like expressing the combination of two qubits as the tensor product, expressing quantum gates as matrices etc. I didn't add it into the question because I wasn't sure it would be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $H | 0 \rangle = | + \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(| 0 \rangle + | 1 \rangle)$.
So, after the two Hadamard gates the state will be 
$$
| 0 \rangle \otimes H| 0 \rangle \otimes H| 0 \rangle = \frac{1}{2} | 0 \rangle \otimes (| 0 \rangle + | 1 \rangle)\otimes (| 0 \rangle + | 1 \rangle) =
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2} (| 000 \rangle + | 001 \rangle + | 010 \rangle + | 011 \rangle)
$$
Now after the application of those two CNOT gates the state will be 
$$
\frac{1}{2} (| 000 \rangle + | 001 \rangle + | 111 \rangle + | 110 \rangle)
$$
The last histogram confirms this (in the 00000 representation the state of q[0] is the far right symbol)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are absolutely right with your understanding but here is the game:
All the Qubits are starting with the **|0>** i.e. **value 0** until the **Hadamard** gate is applied. The Hadamard gates just makes the probability of the Qubit being **0 or 1** to be **50-50** i.e $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\mathbf{0}> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\mathbf{1}>$

---

Now in the second example you applied **H gate** to **q1** and **q2** which gave them the probability of being **0 or 1** to be **50-50**. So, lets see all the **possible initial states of the Qubits and their values as outputs on measurement** first:

---

1. ***State 1:***

   - q0 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **0**---  |
   - q1 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **0**---  |
   - q2 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **0**---  |

     > *Final Output:* **000**
2. ***State 2:***

   - q0 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **1**---  |
   - q1 |**1**> ---OUTPUT : **1**---  |
   - q2 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **1**---  |

     > *Final Output:* **111**
3. ***State 3:***

   - q0 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **0**---  |
   - q1 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **0**---  |
   - q2 |**1**> ---OUTPUT : **1**---  |

     > *Final Output:* **100**
4. ***State 4:***

   - q0 |**0**> ---OUTPUT : **1**---  |
   - q1 |**1**> ---OUTPUT : **1**---  |
   - q2 |**1**> ---OUTPUT : **0**---  |

     > *Final Output:* **011**

---

I hope this helps. Please specify if you are still having trouble in understanding.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! It is preferable that you use [MathJax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49) to typeset your posts.